# How to add Interactive animations in jFrame?

Tags: java, swing, flash, animation

I need to develop a Java programe using NetBeans. And In a JFrame I need to add a a image of planetary system and when the user sets a date and a time, Planets should rotate to their relevant positions. I don't have any idea about this yet. What is the possible way to do this? Please tell me soon

Answer (score 2):

There are literally dozens of ways this might be achieved.

You could use:

- [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)
- [The Timing Framework](https://java.net/projects/TimingFramework)
- [Trident](https://kenai.com/projects/trident/pages/Home)
- [java-universal-tween-engine](https://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/)

The last three are animation engines. Personally, I use the Timing Framework, but that's more to do with what I'm familiar with and my needs at the time.

You'll probably need to do a lot of custom painting to get this to work, take a look at:

- [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

For more details